# Transfering of 565RGB images through socket in java

Tags: java, image, sockets

I want to transfer images through socket in java.
There is a convenient method to send Image like a sequence of bytes.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

But I don't need any format ("PNG","JPEG", etc.). 
Server is implemented on C-language within microcontroller evaluation board and doesn't support them. 
I want to send an image like a sequence of RGB565-pixels.

```
for example: 12_1F      24_C3      ...      67_02 .
```

Server receives it, sets (unsigned short *) pointer on data-field and I have acceses to

```
 pixel [0][0] (12_1F)
```

of image-matrix through this pointer. After operation pointer++ we have access to the next

```
 pixel [0][1] (24_C3)
```

and so on... Is it posible with `ImageIO.write(...)` or in other way?

Answer (score 0):

you could write your own imageWriter...

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/imageio/spec/extending.fm4.html